# Get websocket data in laravel controller

Tags: laravel, websocket

I have an external WebSocket link where im getting data. My requirement is to receive those data in laravel controller and handle them.
How to listen in controller.

Comment: Post your code, unless we can't help here

Comment: Actually we do use echo in resource to listen the update from websocket.
But how to achieve the same thing in controller

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the solution.
[this](https://github.com/Textalk/websocket-php) has helped me.

```
$clientWebSoket = new \WebSocket\Client(
    'wss://somelink'
  );

  $clientWebSoket->send(
    '{"method":"test","symbols":"some data"}'
  );

  while ($i) {
     try {
       $message = $clientWebSoket->receive();
       dump($message);
     } catch (\WebSocket\ConnectionException $e) {
       dd($e);
     }
   }
   $clientWebSoket->close();
```